# How to set a seaborn color map in an arbitrary range?

Tags: python, colors, seaborn

I am creating a heatmap for the correlations between items.

```
sns.heatmap(df_corr, fmt=".2g", cmap='vlag', cbar='True', annot = True)
```

I choose `vlag` as it has red for high values, blue for low values, and white for the middle.

Seaborn automatically sets red for the highest value and blue for the lowest value in the dataframe.

However, as I am tracking Pearson's correlation, the value range is between -1 and 1 - as so I would like to set 1 to be represented by red, -1 with blue, leaving 0 to be represented by white.

How the results looks like:

[image]

How it should be*:

[image]

*(Of course this was generated by "cheating" - setting -1 as value(s) to force the range to be from -1 to 1; I want to set this range without warping my data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is vmin=-1 and vmax=1:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
data = np.random.uniform(low=-0.5, high=0.5, size=(5,5))

hm = sn.heatmap(data = data, cmap= 'vlag', annot = True, vmin=-1, vmax=1)
  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an unorthodox solution. You can "standardize" your data to a range 1 and -1. Even though the theoretical range of Pearson coefficient is [-1, 1]; strong negative correlations are not present in your dataset.

So, you can create another dataframe which contains the data with its max being 1 and min being -1. You can then plot this dataframe to get the desired effect. The advantage this procedure provides is that this technique generalizes to pretty much any dataframe (not verified though).

Here is the code -

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# Setting the initial scale of the data
scale_minimum = -1
scale_maximum = 1
scale_range = scale_maximum-scale_minimum

# Applying the scaling 
df_minimun, df_maximum = df.min(), df.max() # Getting the range of the current dataframe
df_range = df_maximum - df_minimun # The range of the data

df = (df - df_minimun)/(df_range) # Scaling between 0 and 1
df_scaled = df*(scale_range) + scale_minimum # Scaling between  1 and -1
```

Hope this solves your problem.